# C# How to add string to a list from a different file

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and OOP I have two different files. File A where I've created the list.

```
//This file will contain predetermine list of responses.
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Responses
{
    //bot name
    static string nomber = "Jarvis";

    List<string> answer = new List<string>(){
        $"Mi nomber ta {nomber}",
        "Mi ta bon"
    };

    public void AddToList(string value){
        this.answer.Add(value);
    }

    public string Answer(int id)
    {
        return answer.ElementAt(id);
    }    
}
```

And in file B I have these two lines of code to add the string `1` to the list, I've also included the Generics and Linq System in file B.

```
var response = new Responses();
response.answer.Add("1");
```

I've tried creating a method called `AddToList` to pass the value and add it to the list, but with no luck. When I try to display the list at index 2 I'll get an argument out of range instead of the value "1".

*Also both files are located in the same folder.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Can you share the code which tries to access index 2?

Comment: My file is hosted on Repl.it, maybe this will be easier? https://repl.it/@JonattanDavelaa/AlgoAi
The two files i've mentioned above are 
responses.cs and interperter.cs
tbh i'm kinda embarrassed sharing the full code, but it's been in a hour now and i rather throw in the towel at this rate.

Comment: How can you use **response.answer.Add("1")** ? the **answer** is private field

Comment: why dont you use  *response.AddToList("1")*;

Comment: @Miller I've already tried that.

Comment: @PhatHuynh Where? I have not set any of my fields as private.

Comment: After read your source code, I understand your problem. First you **Add new element to Response.answers of Interperter** and it return **id** then you get **Response.answer of Output** by that **id**. Of course you never get that, because they were 2 different instances.

Comment: @PhatHuynh would declaring the answer list as a static solve the issue?

Comment: Can you please put your file B? At what level you are creating instance of class Responses? Every time you create a new instance of Responses, it will be created with 2 element. You might need to create Responses class as singleton to resolve this issue.

Comment: `response.AddToList("1")` : your code works on my computer, the list have 3 items... This has nothing to do with separate files or disk folder.

Comment: Can you share the raised exception or compilation error?

Comment: `private` is the default scope for class fields. If you want it `public`, you have to specify it intentionally.

Comment: When I copy/paste your code and then do `response.AddToList("1"); Console.WriteLine(response.Answer(2));`, I see `"1"` displayed on the console. Please post code that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read your source code, I understand your problem. First you Add new element to Response.answers of Interperter and it return id then you get Response.answer of Output by that id. Of course you never get that, because they were 2 different instances. 
I provide 2 options for you:
**Option 1:**  Make Reponses single instance (singleton)
Responses.cs

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Responses
{
    private static Responses _instance = new Responses();
    public static GetInstance() {
       return _instance;
    }
    //bot name
    static string nomber = "Jarvis";

    List<string> answer = new List<string>(){
        $"Mi nomber ta {nomber}",
        "Mi ta bon"
    };

    public void AddToList(string value){
        this.answer.Add(value);
    }
    public string Answer(int id)
    {
        return answer.ElementAt(id);
    }

}
```

Then change on other files

```cs
//from
var responses = new Responses();
//to
var responses = Responses.GetInstance();

//from
responses.answer.Add()
//to
reponses.AddToList()
```

**Option 2:**  Make Responses static
Response.cs

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Responses
{
    //bot name
    static string nomber = "Jarvis";

    static List<string> answer = new List<string>(){
        $"Mi nomber ta {nomber}",
        "Mi ta bon"
    };

    public static void AddToList(string value){
        this.answer.Add(value);
    }
    public static string Answer(int id)
    {
        return answer.ElementAt(id);
    }

}
```

Output.cs

```cs
using System;

public class Output
{

    public void Return(int respondType, int respond)
    {
        switch(respondType)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine(Responses.Answer(respond));
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Mi no ta kompronde");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Interperter.cs

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class Interpreter
{
    public int UserInputType(string value)
    {
        // Turns the user input into an array of words
        string[] words = value.Split(' ');

        int returnValue = 2;
        //int match = 0;

        Responses.AddToList("1");


        //This stores the correct response to the given question
        //var element = new List<int>(); 

        foreach(var word in words)
        {

            // if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word))
            // {

                foreach(var listOfQuestions in userInputedQuestions)
                {

                    //Convert words in the listOfQuestions to array string to match them with the userInputedQuestion
                    string[] listOfQWords = listOfQuestions.Split(" ");

                    //Check how many words matches the predefined list of questions
                    foreach(var qWord in listOfQWords){
                        if(word == qWord){
                            returnValue = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }


            }

        // }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private List<string> userInputedQuestions = new List<string>(){
        "Ki ta bo nomber?",
        "Konta ku bo?"
    };

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The code is good, but the way he use **Responses** is wrong. He add new item to the instance of Interpreter but try to get new item from Output. (Haha)

Comment: Ah, I did not see that. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark this the answer for help other people who has same problem